# How to read integers entered on a single line using .nextInt .hasNextInt or .hasNext without cause blockage?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to read integers entered one after another on a single line separated by a space.
There will be some way for this code to work without using `.nextLine`, without converting the input to a string and then do the conversion to integer?
The challenge is "not use .nextLine", do not use string or conversions. Reading pure integers and exit from while loop.

```
public static void scannerInts (){          
        int[] list = new int[100];
        int n=0;            
        System.out.print("Input data into one line, [ENTER] to finish: ");            
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                list[n++]= input.nextInt();
            } else {
                input.next();
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
             System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
}
```

PD: I've tried many of the responses from Stack OverFlow and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try to use a `Collection` instead of an array for these numbers.

Comment: "There will be some way for this code to work without using .nextLine", these seem like specific restrictions - class assignment or are you trying to challenge yourself arbitrarily?  Normally, you'd probably use a [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) and iterate over a line.

Comment: The problem is not to use array or collections, but as out of the while loop.

Comment: To be honest, I think these requirements are making that question unsolvable. The allowed methods ignore the line separator, so you can't break the loop, until a non integer was entered.

Comment: Mean that there is no solution using only .nextInt?

Comment: I doubt it. The allowed methods `hasNextInt()` and `hasNext()` both ignore the `enter` (i.e. line separator). Is this an online challenge? Do you have a link to it?

Comment: There is no challenge, but I wanted to show that this could be done
without using nextLine or making conversions.

Comment: You could try to use `while (!input.hasNext(".*(" + System.lineSeparator() + ")|.+$"))`, but this has a bug: it will cut off the last number. Maybe you're interested in fixing that pattern. ([Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.0LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN))

Comment: @Tom It works partially I'll see how it can be fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `System.in` is an infinite stream. Calling `hasNextXXX` will cause `System.in` to prompt if the Scanner doesn't find a token in what has already been read. The user needs to enter some non-integer to terminate the list.

You may, however, use a second Scanner since Scanner can scan a String e.g.:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a list of integers: ");

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner line = new Scanner(in.nextLine());

// optional
line.useDelimiter("\\D+");

while(line.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(line.nextInt());
}

System.out.println("You entered " + list);
```

Using a single Scanner you could also use `findInLine`:

```
for(String token; (token = in.findInLine("-?[1-9]\\d*")) != null;) {
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(token));
}
```

Comment: Were asked not to use conversions, but I like your solution to be simple and easy to code.